Apache server IF URI not working, how to fix it?
I'm making my first website and I have problem configuring my Apache server.
I have the following code
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/kursevi/?$#">
        Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    </If>
    <Else>
        Header always set X-Frame-Debug "%{REQUEST_URI}e"
    </Else>
</IfModule>

If I make request to let's say myDomain.com/kursevi/ I get "ELSE" response meaning X-Frame-Debug in header saying "/kursevi/".
Why isn't then "IF" statement catching that?
I also tried the following IF statement
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/kursevi' || %{REQUEST_URI} == '/kursevi/'">
But to no good.
